# How to update the working tree to a commit while keeping the index?

Tags: git

I have made some changes and staged them all into the index. Now I would like to throw away the working tree, and make it look exactly like the committed `HEAD`, without throwing away the index.  How can this be achieved?

Everything I've looked at is geared toward the opposite: preserving the working tree while manipulating the index, or else manipulating both.

For instance, is there some way of stashing that index, and then later staging  those stashed changes without doing anything to the working tree?

For reference, the following hacky achieves the effect, at least when the materials involved are patchable text files. Assume all changes have been staged with `git add`:

```
# apply the staged diff to the working tree, in reverse; i.e. undo it.
git diff --cached | git apply -R
```

After this, `git diff --cached` continues to show the staged changes, and `git diff` shows the reverse diff: those changes being undone relative to the index.

Answers to this question must reproduce the effect of the above command pipeline.

Comment: `git checkout -- .` should reset your working directory only, leaving the stage untouched.

Comment: @TimBiegelsen Have you read the documentation? Without a <tree-ish> argument, this will reset the working copy to the index. Since I have staged everything (index == working), it has no effect. With a <tree-ish> argument, it affects the index!

Comment: Write the index as a commit with `git write-tree`. Save the resulting hash ID, do the stuff that wrecks the index, then fix it up with `git read-tree` from the written tree.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: not a dup, as the goal is to save the *index* across this operation.

Comment: I guess I found it a bit confusing about the question this part: "I would like to throw away the working tree, and make it look exactly like the committed HEAD, without throwing away the index." and then in the comment you write "Since I have staged everything (index == working),". If index == working, doesn't a simple stash solve your problem? And what also if index == working what do you mean by "throw away the working tree, and make it look exactly like the committed HEAD, without throwing away the index"

Answer (score 0):

There's a method to do this with `git stash`.  I happen to really dislike `git stash` but I'll write it out anyway:

1. Run `git stash`: this saves both the index and the work-tree, under the name `refs/stash`.  It then runs `git reset --hard` so now your index and work-tree look the way you want.
2. Do whatever you like with your work-tree
3. To restore the index *and* the work-tree to the state they had in step 1, run `git stash apply --index` or `git stash branch branch-name`.  The latter will create a new branch using the hash ID of the parent of the stash (the commit that was active at the time you made the stash), `git checkout` that branch, and run `git stash apply --index`.

Note that this also restores the work-tree, which you did not necessarily want.  It restores the index using `git apply --index`, and restores the work-tree using `git-merge-recursive`.  Either or both steps can fail, except when applying to something that matches the original commit (hence `git stash branch` always succeeds).

Since you *only* really want to save and restore the index, we can go lower-level:

1. `hash=git write-tree`: writes out the index as a new (or re-used) Git *tree* object and saves the resulting hash
2. `git reset --hard`: work-tree and index both match commit now
3. `git read-tree $hash`: updates the index to match the given hash, without touching the work-tree.

The `read-tree` command is pretty complicated and can do a lot of other things, but this particular operation is not.

Comment: I will try that; what I boiled down my approach to is simply this: `git diff --cached | git apply -R`!  That's it. But it involves generating a patch that trombones out of git and back, so it's kind of ugly and perhaps won't work with nicely with binary content (not a problem I have in my scenario).

Comment: BTW it's not at all clear to me *why* you want to do this. The only thing you can really do with the index is commit it, for which `git write-tree` is the first step (the rest being `git commit-tree` and `git update-ref`).

Comment: I have files that are newly added in HEAD, and would like to simplify these, while keeping the full definitions to go into a new commit. I think it can be done like this, too: commit the changes into a new commit. Then commit a revert of that commit. Then interactively rebase, squashing the two older commits.

Answer (score 0):

Does `git stash --keep-index` help? Something along the lines:

```
git stash --keep-index # stash working tree without the index
git stash # stash just the index
git stash drop <stashid-of-wt-without-index>
```

EDIT: Sorry for the confusion. I use this from a GUI (magit) and it's kinda clearer which one you'd need.

Comment: The only documented effect of `--no-keep-index` in `stash` is to override an implicit `--keep-index` set up by `-p/--patch`.